# strtok in kohana

Tags: php, kohana

I'm not able to understand meaning of following lines. I want to configure an existing project in Kohana. I searched in documentation but it's really hard to find. I don't know which in version it was developed, I'm configuring it in kohana-3.2.

```
$devName = strtok($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], '.');
$devName = strtok('.');
$devName = 'production';
$zcf = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPPATH . 'config/website.ini');
Zend_Registry::set('config', $zcf->$devName);
$db = Zend_Db::factory($zcf->$devName->db);
Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($db);
Zend_Registry::set('db', $db);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, that use of `strtok` seems pretty pointless, since the value is overwritten with `'production'` anyway. What's your question with this?

Comment: Where do these lines come from anyway? I haven't seen them in the official docs. Furthermore, it uses Zend Framework and not Kohana. What am I missing?

Comment: Some Zend modules are compatible with Kohana. KutePHP - give us more info: what you want to achieve with this code and what for do you need to know the version of Kohana?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get know the version of Kohana used in project you can:

1. One big difference Koahan 2 branch from Kohana 3 branch is HMVC. It uses `Request::factory()` method to call another request at any time during the request flow. Try to run `Request::factory()`. If class and method are found - you use Koahana 3 branch, if they not - Koahana 2 branch.
2. To load configuration values from config files in the cascading filesystem Kohana 3.0-3.1 uses `Kohana::config(<config_file_name>)` but Kohana 3.2 uses `Kohana::$config->load(<config_file_name>)`.

All I can remember :)

Comment: Hey Thanks ! I wanted to configure the project on my machine. After reading and comparing the methods and classes, I could guess its version :)